# Kakao login giving KOE006

Tags: magento, magento2, kakao

I am trying to add kakao login to my magento store but while calling I am getting this error after login

[image]

So I check the error https://developers.kakao.com/docs/latest/en/kakaologin/trouble-shooting against KOE006 which says 'You used an unregistered Redirect URI when requesting an authorization code.'. So I verified my redirect URI at  [My Application] > [Kakao Login] which was correct.

Can you please let me know it's reason and solution?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake I was using the key Native app key. Rather correct key is REST API key. I hope it will help you and save your time.